# In Odoo 11 CE, how can I filter records returned from a computed field based on values from a related model?

Tags: filtering, odoo-11, computed-field

In Odoo V11 CE, I'm trying to figure out how to fetch the 'amount' field from hr.payslip.line where 'code' = "NET" and display that field in the form view for the parent hr.payslip.

hr.payslip has a One2many relationship with hr.payslip.line through the related field "slip_id".  In my situation, each payslip has multiple payslip lines, but only one of the lines has the 'code' "NET".

This is the code I have so far:

```
class HrPayslip(models.Model):
 _name = "hr.payslip"
 _inherit = ['hr.payslip', 'mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin']

 net_pay = fields.Float(string='Net Pay', compute='_get_netpay')

@api.multi
 def _get_netpay(self):
for line in self:
 line.net_pay = self.env['hr.payslip.line'].search([('code', '=', "NET")], limit = 1).amount
```

I thought it was working but then I realised that it is not fetching the 'amount' value from the correct "code = NET" line in the hr.payslip.line table.  No matter which payslip I am looking at, the 'net_pay' value is being returned from the same line, roughly in the middle of the table.

I thought the "self.env" would mean that only records that were related through the "slip_id" would be considered, but it seems I don't understand what that actually does.

How can I make the computed field look for lines that have the code "NET" AND that have a slip_id that matches the id of the parent payslip?